# Community background process reviews approval policy

Tags: support, suggested-edits, community

Which is the policy adopted by Community background process regarding to the reviews approval?
I do not understand why a review I made on spelling and code formatting has been rejected.

Comment: For what it's worth, your suggested edit was fine.  The only thing I would have done differently would be editing out the "Thanks in advance" at the end.  Keep up the good work.

Comment: See [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137906/community-background-process-reviews-approval-policy#comment387216_137908) of mine. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users who have enough reputation to review edits can review edits.

It takes two such people to reject an edit - they will normally explain their (unrelated) reasoning in the rejection.

Also see [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

---

Looking at the rejection by "community" that @jadarnl27 linked to in the comment, I would say that your edit was superseded by a more significant edit by another user and the system took that one, rejecting yours in the process.

Comment: I think they're probably talking about [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/301314), which was "Rejected by Community♦"

Comment: I'm sorry I have been not so clear, but I refer to the Community background process. Question updated.

Comment: @ADC It's possible that the person who reviewed your suggested edit chose "improve" (rather than "approve" or "reject"), and then unchecked the "was this helpful?" checkbox.  That would reject your suggested edit (as outlined in the post Oded linked to).

Comment: @jadarnel27 true, that person was Tim as can be seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11233601/revisions) (he edited three minutes after ADC suggested his edit) - maybe he unticked the checkbox by mistake you can ask him in a comment about this.